# Why do I sometimes get double increases in my score when I catch a star?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a videogame and a problme I'm currently running into is the fact that when I'm testing the game I often get double or triple increases in the score when I catch one Star. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Below you will find the script that handles score increases. Thanks in advance

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StarCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

    int Score;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball")) // Change this from an update method that runs every frame to a method that only runs when things change (Score script score display method)
        {
            Score = ScoreScript.scoreValue;
            ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
            Score = ScoreScript.scoreValue;

            if (Score == ScoreScript.scoreValue)
            {
                Debug.Log("My instance: " + GetInstanceID());
                Debug.Log("Other instance: " + other.gameObject.GetInstanceID());
            }

        }

    }

    private IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {

        ScoreScript.score.color = Color.yellow;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ScoreScript.score.color = Color.white;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

The score should only increase by 1 for each star that is catched

Comment: Are there more `StarCollision` scripts than you'd want?  If you pause the game while playing and type "t:StarCollision" into the Hierarchy search, it'll show all objects with that script attached.  There's also the possibility you have too many colliders on the White Ball object and it's triggering the code more than once.

Comment: Add these two lines and let us know what gets output when you get multiple score increases from touching one star: `Debug.Log("My instance: "+GetInstanceID());` `Debug.Log("Other instance: "+other.gameObject.GetInstanceID());`

Comment: Why don't you replace your first line with Score = ScoreScript.scoreValue + 1

Comment: Also, yeah the `Score` field seems completely redundant.

Comment: The Score field was made entirely for debuging purposses, I will delete it when I solve the problem

Comment: Output: My instance: -58282
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StarCollision:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2 Scripts/StarCollision.cs:20)

Comment: Other instance: -44392
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StarCollision:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2 Scripts/StarCollision.cs:21)

Comment: That's all it printed and the score went up by multiple points? Please edit your question to show where you put the `Debug.Log` statements in the code.

Comment: I think Foggzie is on the right track. There's likely multiple collisions firing. You might need to add a property to track if the object has been touched (depending on how your game works).

Comment: @Foggzie It displays the following : "Path: Star"

Comment: Please confirm that it only outputs the pair of debug statements **once each** when `ScoreScript.scoreValue` increases by more than 1, as your earlier comments suggest.  The number of times each gets printed and what it says for the instance IDs is important for pinpointing the exact cause of the issue.

Comment: @Ruzihm For a score of 5 where the game incremented the score from 1 to 2 for the first star 2-3 for the second and 3-5 for the 4th time I received: Other instance: -44392
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StarCollision:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2 Scripts/StarCollision.cs:21)

5 times. My instance: -72156
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StarCollision:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2 Scripts/StarCollision.cs:20)

1 time.

Comment: My instance: -72172
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StarCollision:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2 Scripts/StarCollision.cs:20)
1 time

Comment: My instance: -72124
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StarCollision:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Scene 2 Scripts/StarCollision.cs:20)
2 times

Comment: `Score = ScoreScript.scoreValue; if (Score == ScoreScript.scoreValue)`. If this is ever false, you've done something terribly, terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to disable collision on the star immediately after a collision with the ball occurs. To use this on a pooled star, you would need to re-enable the collision when the star is enabled again:

```
Collider2D myCollider;

private void Awake()
{
    myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

private void OnEnable() 
{
    myCollider.enabled = true;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball")) 
    {
        // Disable this collider immediately to prevent redundant scoring, sound cues, etc.
        myCollider.enabled = false;

        ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
        StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
    }
}
```

If you decide you need collision on the star while the coroutine is occurring, you can add a field to `StarCollision` that ensures that the score will only increase once. For a pooled star, again, you would need to ensure that it is reset in `OnEnable`:

```
private bool alreadyScored = false;    

private void OnEnable()
{
    alreadyScored = false;
}


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball")) 
    {
        if (!alreadyScored) 
        {
            ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());

            alreadyScored = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this doesn't work because it makes the clones of my star game object inactive. (i'm using an object pooler to prevent garbage collection)

Comment: Alright thanks man. I tested it a couple of times and it seems to work